# Relative path to immeadiate parent in reverse nested aggregation elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to define the **path** parameter in **reverse nested aggregation** in **Elasticsearch** relative to the node being aggregated on? So for eg if my document is:

```
{
    "document": {
        "nodes": [
           {
                "node_1_1": {
                    "somefield_1":"somevalue_1"
                },
                "node_1_2": {
                    "somefield_2":"somevalue_2"
                }
            },
            {
                "node_2_3": {
                     "somefield_3":"somevalue_3"
                },
                "node_2_4": {
                     "somefield_4":"somevalue_4"                  
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to flter on **somefield_1** for **somevalue_1** and then use reverse nesting and travese upto the **first element of the array nodes** and not the root of the document?

thanks
cheers
Kiran

Comment: @N Kiran Kumar Kowlgi can you please share your expected search result ?

Comment: Can you please share your index mapping?